# Load MPMoviePlayer Without playing video. Just preview

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayer, m4v

I am playing a m4v video in my app. It is playing fine but i just want to load the video without playing it. Just the preview.

I am using following code.

```
-(void)test
{
    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"YOUR_PATH"]];
    //[self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
    [self.player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview: self.player.view];

}
```

But If i am uncommenting `[self.player prepareToPlay];`, It is starting to play.

If I comment `[self.player prepareToPlay];`, video is not loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
-(void)test
{
    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"YOUR_PATH"]];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player play];
    [self performSelector:@selector(pausePlayer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    [self.player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
    [self.player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview: self.player.view];

}
-(void)pausePlayer
{
    if (self.player)
    {
        [self.player pause];
    }
}
```